# Converting pixel values to temperature OpenCV

Tags: python, image-preprocessing, opencv

I am converting a pixel values to temp (values of a thermal image). But after conversion output image is not except able. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Thermal image
img = cv2.imread('IR2.bmp',0)

print(img)
pixel=np.asarray(img)

# storing in pixel array
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
   for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
      print(pixel[i][j])

# converting pixel value to temperature values
r,c=(230,304)

arr = np.zeros([230,304])
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
   for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
        arr[i][j] = 9.2+(pixel[i][j]/255)*26.2

print(arr)

# showing the converted image

cv2.imshow('converted',arr)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Input Thermal Image]
[image: Output image]

Comment: Your first for-loop "storing in pixel array" doesn't do anything, it just prints the array

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406075/getting-temperature-from-pixel-data

Comment: Yes, for storing the pixel-i have done this just to check...But my major concern is the output image.I want the image with temp. values.

Comment: you could calculate it much faster in one line `arr = 9.2 + (img/255) * 26.2` - without `np.asarray`, `np.zeros`, `for`-loops. But it gives the same values which are too small and they all looks like white color.

Comment: Yes, that the problem..the final image is white...but it should not be...as the converted values are small,it should be in black shade..